# Wrap several ggplot2 functions and use the wrapper with operator "+" in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I start with the **question**: is there a way to create a function, say `ggColors`, which wraps several other functions from package `ggplot2`? That function should add up with `ggplot` object using operator `+` (and not `%>%` operator) as in this example:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,disp, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p + ggColors()
```

Where `ggColors` should be something like this:

```
ggColors <- function(values = NULL, name = NULL, cold.colors = TRUE) {
    # Some conditions:
    if (is.null(values)){
        if (cold.colors) {
            values <- c("darkblue","blue", "green")
        } else {
            values <- c("red","orange", "yellow")
        }
    }     
    # Modified default values of `ggplot2` functions:
    scale_color_manual(name = name, values = values) +
    scale_fill_manual (name = name, values = values)
}
```

The problem is that `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` do not add up, as they do not result in `ggplot` object inside the function `ggColors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggColors` should return a list of plot elements. Then all of the elements of the returned list can be added to a plot using `+`:

```
  ggColors <- function(values = NULL, name = NULL, cold.colors = TRUE) {
    # Some conditions:
    if (is.null(values)){
      if (cold.colors) {
        values <- c("darkblue","blue", "green")
      } else {
        values <- c("red","orange", "yellow")
      }
    }     
    # Modified default values of `ggplot2` functions:
    return(list(scale_color_manual(name = name, values = values),
                scale_fill_manual (name = name, values = values)))
  }
```

Then,

```
p + ggColors()
```